# MySQL select distinct not getting desired query result

Tags: mysql, distinct

I have a database table with the following data:

```
+--------------------+-----------------------------+  
|    order_no        |   part                      |   
+--------------------+-----------------------------+  
| AAAAAAAAAAAAA      |  QQQQQQQQ-WWW               |  
| AAAAAAAAAAAAA      |  EEEEEEEE-TTT               |  
| BBBBBBBBBBBBB      |  33333333-333               |  
| BBBBBBBBBBBBB      |  44444444-444               |  
| BBBBBBBBBBBBB      |  EEEEEEEE-TTT               |  
+--------------------+-----------------------------+
```

My problem is that I can't make a query to produce this result:

```
+----------------+-------------------------------------------+
|    order_no    |   part                                    |
+----------------+-------------------------------------------+
| AAAAAAAAAAAAA  |  QQQQQQQQ-WWW, EEEEEEEE-TTT               |  
| BBBBBBBBBBBBB  |  33333333-333, 44444444-444, EEEEEEEE-TTT |  
+----------------+-------------------------------------------+
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You are looking for http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/group-by-functions.html#function_group-concat

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [`group_concat`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/group-by-functions.html#function_group-concat) aggregate function is just what the doctor ordered:

```
SELECT   order_no, GROUP_CONCAT(part SEPARATOR ', ')
FROM     mytable
GROUP BY order_no
```

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

```
SELECT order_no, GROUP_CONCAT(string SEPARATOR ', ') FROM table GROUP BY order_no;
```